# Type mismatch when trying to loop through dictionary?

Tags: vba, dictionary

I created a function called AddRowsToDictionary as a Dictionary.

Inside the function I created a dictionary:

```
Dim dict As Dictionary
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

I return dict to AddRowsToDictionary:

```
Set addRowstoDictionary = dict
```

But I get a

> "ByRef argument type mismatch error"

when I loop through the function dictionary (AddRowsToDictionary), but not the dictionary inside the function (dict).

Error:

```
Dim key As Variant

    For Each key In addRowstoDictionary.Keys

        Debug.Print key, addRowstoDictionary(key)

    Next
```

No Error:

```
 Dim key As Variant

    For Each key In dict.Keys

        Debug.Print key, dict(key)

    Next
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your code to add a minimal repro of the problem, including a full `addRowstoDictionary` function. Does not need to be your full code, just enough to show the problem you describe. I'd guess VBA is not able to distinguish whether `addRowstoDictionary(key)` is trying to *call the function* with argument `key` or trying to access the returned dictionary by key value.  `addRowstoDictionary()(key)` is less ambiguous and may work, but that's a terribly inefficient way to do it.

Comment: You are misunderstanding how a function works. According to your limited code, your call to addRowsToDictionary will always return a new dictionary.  The .Keys method works because a dictionary has been returned.  Addrowstodictionary(key) will not work because VBA cannot disambiguate a function call to addrowstodictionary and the default method of .Item(key), you would likely need to rewrite this line as addrowstodictionary()(Key).  However,this might be a pointless exercise as your function seemingly only ever  returns a new empty dictionary.